# Deduce amount of traffic routed out of the Tor network compared traffic routed to hidden services

Tags: exit-relays, hsdir, stats

On the metrics page of the Tor network, there are two statistics that caught my eye: There is one dataset on the [Onion-service traffic (both v2 & v3)](https://metrics.torproject.org/hidserv-rend-relayed-cells.html) and another dataset [listing traffic for guards and exit nodes](https://metrics.torproject.org/bandwidth-flags.html).

Now I was wondering if those two datasets are comparable in a sense that one can deduce the relative amount of traffic staying within the Tor network by simple division: `(HS traffic/Exit node traffic) = %` of traffic residing within the Tor network (e.g. hits an HS).

Is my thinking correct or are those traffic measurements actually not comparable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think your formula for approx hidden service traffic is right.